# How can I check the version of a package online before installing?

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew

For example, when I run

```
brew search octave
```

I see:

```
homebrew/science/octave                Caskroom/cask/octave
```

I don't know which of these to install so I want to check the version of these programs. Is there any way to get it without installing?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can get information on each of the hits:

```
brew info octave
brew info --cask evernote
```

In both cases, these may require you to "tap" the containing levels, but it gives you the command to run for each as needed.

From the first package information, you should get an info URL of https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/blob/master/octave.rb and then could inspect the source of that octave installation. Repeat for the cask and then you can decide or not to install one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

You have two versions because one is command-line and the other is a Graphical User Interface (GUI). You can check their versions with the commands below. I use `libreoffice` as `octave` is no longer a cask:

```
$ brew info octave
octave: stable 5.1.0 (bottled), HEAD
High-level interpreted language for numerical computing
https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/index.html
...
$ brew cask info libreoffice
libreoffice: 6.3.4
https://www.libreoffice.org/
...
```

This solution works immediately and avoids "tapping" and downloading a repo (which as of January 2020 requires entering a Github username and password).

Answer (score 0):

Check version via `brew info <package_name>` command, `cask` command is not valid any more. If you know you are searching for a GUI app, you can specify `brew info --cask <package_name>`.

E.g.

```
$ brew info --cask libreoffice
libreoffice: 7.0.4             <----- VERSION COMES HERE
https://www.libreoffice.org/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/HEAD/Casks/libreoffice.rb
==> Name
LibreOffice
==> Description
Free cross-platform office suite
...
```

P.S. More simple way I tried is to google like `evernote version brew`, and on Brew page there's [info](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/evernote).

P.P.S. Could anyone open it up how to check JSON package directly from formulae/cask name, e.g. [this](https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask/evernote.json)?

Comment: You can run the json file through `jq` to extract the version number: `curl -s https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask/evernote.json | jq -r .version`